# Finite Difference Derivative on Extrapolated Data

Tags: list-manipulation, calculus-and-analysis, interpolation

I have an (in reality complex) function on a grid, which approximately vanishes at the boundaries of the grid, and which I want to project onto a larger grid.
Example:

```
fx = Interpolation[
   Transpose[{Range[-2.5, 2.5, 0.01], 
     Exp[-x^2] /. x -> Range[-2.5, 2.5, 0.01]}], 
   "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {0 &, "WarningMessage" -> False}];
fx2 = Transpose[{Range[-3, 3, 0.01], 
    fx[p] /. p -> Range[-3, 3, 0.01]}];
```

Then I want to take the derivative of this function:

```
dfx2 = Transpose[{fx2[[All, 1]], NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[1], fx2[[All, 1]], 
     fx2[[All, 2]], "DifferenceOrder" -> 5]}];
```

If I then ListPlot this derivative, I get these ugly points at the boundary of the first grid:

[image: ListPlot[dfx2]]

I know that they come for the discontinuity at the boundary of the first grid but I have to get rid of them.
Since this problem arises inside a much more complex code, there are a few things I can't change:

1. I can't change the order of the operations (new grid comes before derivative).
2. I don't know the new grid size and also not the old grid size (I don't know beforehand at which positions these ugly points occur)

I have two ideas how to fix this:

1. Find a way that Mathematica extrapolates the function in a way that it behaves approximately like the original function (which I also don't know) avoiding the sudden jump  to zero. However, I know that it behaves like `A Exp[(x-b)^2/c]` at the boundaries.
2. Identify these ugly points after they occur and replace them with points that make the function smooth.

Is there a better third way? And if not, which way would you choose and how would you implement it?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just taking the derivative of the interpolation functions directly?

Comment: Do you also have a potential functional form for the non-boundaries of the original function?  If so why not fit that function and then take the derivative of the estimated function?

Comment: If you really must first take interpolation points and then differentiate, you must make sure that there is no discontinuity. You may achieve this by setting: ""ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Exp[-2.5^2] &,"

Comment: @ Sjoerd Smit  That produces the same problem for me after doing it twice.  @JimB No I don't   @ Daniel Huber Also produces the same problem after two iterations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what you can do: you can interpolate the derivative of `fx` and then integrate it. The derivative of `fx` is well-behaved outside of the function range:

```
Plot[fx'[x], {x, -3, 3}]
```

> [image]

So instead of interpolating the function and differentiating it, you can interpolate the derivative and integrate it:

```
fx2 = Derivative[-1] @ Interpolation[
   Transpose[{Range[-3, 3, 0.01], fx'[Range[-3, 3, 0.01]]}]
];
Plot[{fx2[x], fx2'[x]}, {x, -3, 3}]
```

Note that you might have to consider constant offsets when you integrate.

> [image]

## Update

It looks like what's necessary here is a method to make the interpolation function go to zero smoothly outside of the data range. Here's an example of how you could do that:

```
smoothenToZero[x_, nf_NearestFunction, lambda : _ : 1] := With[{
    nearestXY = First@nf[x, 1]
 },
   nearestXY[[2]] * Exp[-Divide[Subtract[nearestXY[[1]], x], lambda]^2]
];
data = Table[{x, Exp[-x^2]}, {x, -3, 3, 0.01}];
nf = Nearest[data[[All, 1]] -> data];
int = Interpolation[data,
  "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {
    smoothenToZero[#, nf, 1] &,
    "WarningMessage" -> False
   }
];
LogPlot[int[x], {x, -5, 5}]
```

> [image]

As you can see, the function is now at least continuous at the transition from interpolation to extrapolation. You may need to tinker with the transition expression (maybe find one that also matches the derivatives nicely), but I hope this helps to make progress.

Comment: thank you and sorry, it's a neat solution, however, in my case, it didn't work since I have to repeat this procedure multiple times on the same function and it still produces ugly points at the boundary of the first grid after 2 iterations.

Comment: Why exactly do you need to do this? What's wrong with using the original extrapolated function? In any case, you could consider using convolutions to smoothen things out if spikes keep popping up.

Comment: We are simulating the evolution of a quantum wavefunction. In order to do so we project it onto a discrete grid. However, since the position of the wavefunction on that grid changes rapidly, we want an adaptive grid, which moves together with the wavefunction such that we don't have to use an incredible large grid. (Calculation time goes approximately with gridsize^2). We make the new grid after each timestep dependent on the mean and standard deviation of the current wave packet. This works well so far. But sometimes the discontinuities produce unphysical results. Does that make sense? :)

Comment: @Luke Yes, I see what you want. I'm not sure what would be the proper way to do this, though. You always end up with some sort of rounding error when you do this, so I think this needs some careful consideration. You probably need to find a better way to smoothen the edges of the function to zero rather than an abrupt step.

Comment: @Luke I updated the answer with a suggestion for smoothening the transition to zero. It's unlikely that this is exactly what you need, but I hope it gives you some new ideas about how to continue.

Comment: thank you very much! I will play around with it until it works ;)